# Difference between analog and digital servos?

Tags: digital-servo, analog-servo, servo

I've noticed that there is often a price gap between analog and digital servos. What is the difference between an analog and digital servo and why is a digital servo better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Analog Servos

Analog RC servos use a form of **p**ulse **w**idth **m**odulation (PWM) to control the speed of the servo. It's basically switch the motor on and off quickly (Commonly 50 times per second). The motor rotates a certain angle depending on the width of the on-pulse.

[image: Example of PWM]

### Digital servos

Digital servos also use PWM, but at a much higher frequency (6 times that of a analog servo). They contain a microprocessor that received the signal, and then send the PWM to the motor

### Comparison

The digital motor will be smooth and react faster, but it's more complex and therefore more expensive

Comment: "Digital servos also use OWM" — do you mean PWM?